# How to find position of a row which has the maximum occupied columns in excel using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

My excel file consists of garbage value present above my header row, I want to find out the index position of row which has the maximum number of occupied column and then assign it as the header row

Comment: you need to provide a minimal reproducible example, the question is currently too vague

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about what you mean as header, I'll assume it is the first row.

So this will iterate through the rows, find the first row with the largest amount of data (counted as fewest of empty cells from the end), and delete all rows above this row.

The data I work with in CSV format:

```
some,,,
useless,01/01/70,,
0,garbage,,
according,,to author,
head1,head2,head3,head4
dat1,dat2,dat3,dat4
dat2,dat3,dat4,dat5
dat3,dat4,dat5,dat6
```

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("./garbage.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

data_len = list[int]()  # list for data length

for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True):  # iterate through rows
    # print(len(row))  # always the same since this is a table
    for i in reversed(range(len(row))):  # iterate through cells from end to beginning
        if row[i] is not None:  # if cell is not empty
            data_len.append(i)  # save cell position in data length list
            break  # move to next row

header_index = data_len.index(max(data_len))  # get first index of max data length
ws.delete_rows(0, header_index)  # delete from top to header index

for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True):  # only header and data remain
    print(row)
```

NB. it will work the criterion for data length is correct, but would definitely not use it in production.